# Oracle - How to write simple PL/SQL procedure

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

I need to create a table with sessions. New users who are successfully authenticated will be added to the table. Every time when the users are opening the pages the user will checked in this table. So I want to use PL/SQL procedure which will run every minute and delete sessions older than 30 minutes to flush the "death" sessions.

Or maybe executing `DELETE FROM "Dates" WHERE "Date" < SYSDATE - 1/48;` every time when pages are reloaded will be a more optimized solution?

Comment: Errr, out of curiosity, why a PL/SQL procedure? Is this meant to be run by dbms_scheduler or something?

Comment: _Or maybe if I execute ... every time when pages are reloaded_ Probably should avoid doing kill off "dead sessions" during page loads, but do it as part of a background process that runs occasionally (say every 5 minutes) Even once a minute will put far less load on the server than executing for every page load. (Assuming a slightly successful web application.) And avoid slowing down page loads for things it the page doesn't need. As Jeff Atword says, "Performance is a Feature." http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/06/performance-is-a-feature.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need procedure to do that. Simple delete query is enough.

```
DELETE FROM "Dates" WHERE "Date" < SYSDATE - 1/48;
```

If you necessarily need procedure, you should wrap this query into proc.

Comment: Here is more info: I need to create a table with sessions. New users who are successfully authenticated will be added to the table. Every time when the users are opening the pages the user will checked in this table. So I want to use PL/SQL procedure which will run every minute and delete sessions bigger than 30 min to flush the "death" sessions. Or maybe if I execute this "DELETE FROM "Dates" WHERE "Date" < SYSDATE - 1/48;" every time when pages are reloaded will be more optimized solution?

Comment: Which one of the three (sql statement, trigger, pl/sql procedure) uses less hardware resources?

Comment: I've moved the more info to the question

Comment: try this way create a table first and whenever someone logins to the account with username ,insert an entry into the that table (this in done by trigger) ,before inserting trigger will check your condition of what is required.

Answer (score 3):

```
delete 
from table
where date_column < sysdate - 30/1440;
```

1 is a day

1/1440 is a minute

30/1440 equals 30 minutes

Comment: Spot on, don't worry about going down the PL/SQL route unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
delete from mytable
  where mytable.datefield < sysdate - .02083333333333333333;
commit;
```

.02083333333333333333 is 1800 / 86400  which is 30 minutes in seconds / seconds in a day

If you are writing a trigger or a stored procedure you would use PL/SQL.  Please elaborate a little more.